# Simplest slideshow in HTML5 canvas, canvas.context.clearRect not working with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is a code of a very simple slideshow, that should show 4 images in 4 seconds, one image per second. Instead, I get a 4-second delay and then all the images get drawn on top of each other. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script langugage="javascript">
// 4 images
var image0 = new Image();
image0.src = "img/image0.png";
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "img/image1.png";
var image0 = new Image();
image2.src = "img/image2.png";
var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "img/image3.png";
// array of 4 images
images = new Array(image0, image1, image2, image3);

// this is the main function
function draw(){
    myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    counter=0; // this is the index of the next image to be shown
    for (var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
        setTimeout(draw_next_image, 1000);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height)
    }
}
// this is the function called after each timeout to draw next image
function draw_next_image(){
    ctx.drawImage(images[counter], 0, 0);
    counter++;
    if (counter>images.length) {counter=0;}
}

window.onload = draw;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE: THE ANSWER IS:**

In the code above I mistakingly assumed that `getTimeout` function is synchronous, i.e. I expected, that upon its call the program execution is going to stop, wait 1000 milliseconds, then call the `draw_next_image` and only then execute `ctx.clearRect`.

In reality Javascript doesn't work like that. In fact `getTimeout` is asynchronous, i.e. `getTimeout` sets a Timeout and returns almost instantly and the code execution continues, so that `ctx.clearRect` gets called right away and actually **prior** to `draw_next_image`. So, by the time Timeout expires and calls `draw_next_image`, execution of code may reach and arbitrary line of code. In my case all the 4 `clearRect` are going to be called almost at the same time, long before expiration of Timeouts. Then 1000 milliseconds later, all the 4 timeouts are going to expire almost immediately one after another, and all the 4 images going to be drawn almost at the same time, too, without `clearRects`, which got executed long before.

Comment: Please add your answer as an actual answer instead of adding it to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in your code you are treating asynchronous functions as if they where synchronous.

The main points are here:

```
image0.src = "img/image0.png";
image1.src = "img/image1.png";
image2.src = "img/image2.png";
image3.src = "img/image3.png";
...
setTimeout(draw_next, delayInMilliseconds);
```

As these calls just falls through once they are invoked, and your code starts to execute the next step before the result from these are (possibly) ready.

You therefor need to *chain* your calls based on events, for example:

```
//image counter as there is no guarantee that the last images loaded
//is the last one to finish
var loaded = 0, numOfImages = 4;

//first part of chain, invoke async load
var image0 = document.createElement('img'); //this will work in new Chrome
var image1 = document.createElement('img'); //instead of new Image
var image2 = document.createElement('img');
var image3 = document.createElement('img');

//common event handler when images has loaded with counter
//to know that all images has loaded
image0.onload = image1.onload = 
image2.onload = image3.onload = function(e) {
    loaded++;
    if (loaded === numOfImages)
        draw();   // <-- second part of chain, invoke loop
}

//show if any error occurs
image0.onerror = image1.onerror = 
image2.onerror = image3.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
}

//invoke async loading... you can put these four into your
//window.onload if you want to
image0.src = "img/image0.png";
image1.src = "img/image1.png";
image2.src = "img/image2.png";
image3.src = "img/image3.png";

// this is the main function
function draw() {

    var images = new Array(image0, image1, image2, image3),
        counter = 0,
        delayInMilliseconds = 4000,
        maxNum = images.length - 1,

        myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
        ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d'),

        me = this; //this we need for setTimeout()

    //third part of chain, have a function to invoke by setTimeout
    this._draw = function() {

        //if the next image will cover the canvas
        //there is no real need to clear the canvas first.
        //I'll leave it here as you ask for this specifically
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height)
        ctx.drawImage(images[counter++], 0, 0);
        if (counter > maxNum) counter = 0;

        setTimeout(me._draw, delayInMilliseconds); //use me instead of this
    }
    this._draw(); //START the loop
}
```

Working demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/dhxNz/

The `_draw()` is wrapped in `draw()` to localize the variables and also to make sure that `_draw()` doesn't end up on the `window` object. For the same reason we store a reference to `this` as `this` is changed to `window` object when its code is invoked. `me` (or what you want to call it) makes sure that we are calling on the right object so that we have access to the local variables (canvas, ctx, counter etc.).

Comment: Ok, Ken, thank you for answer and suggestions. So basicly, setTimeout is asynchronous and returns instantly and next line of code gets executed. Besides, why did you replace static images with `document.createElement('img');`? Is it better in any way?

Comment: Correct - `setTimeout` just queues an event in the event queue to execute the code at the timeout and then continues so the next line of code will be executed. The reason for `createElement` is that there has been reported problems with the newer Chrome that ` new Image` doesn't work with it. This way will work.

Answer (score 2):

How about this.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slider</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
// The 3 images
var im1 = new Image();
im1.src = "img/kitten1.jpg";
var im2 = new Image();
im2.src = "img/kitten2.jpg";
var im3 = new Image();
im3.src = "img/kitten3.jpg";

// Starting position of the 3 images
var x1 = 0;
var x2 = -600;
var x3 = -1200;

var counter = 0;
var img_count = 0;

// Canvas
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//This draws the first image when the page is loaded
ctx.drawImage(im1, x1, 0);

function sliderMove() {
    if(counter <= 590) {
        x1+=10;
        ctx.drawImage(im1,x1,0);
        x2+=10;
        ctx.drawImage(im2,x2,0);
        x3+=10;         
        ctx.drawImage(im3,x3,0);


        counter+=10;
    }
    else {
        counter = 0;
        img_count++

        if(img_count == 1) {
            x1 = -1200;
        }else if(img_count == 2) {
            x2 = -1200;
        }else if(img_count == 3) {
            x3 = -1200;
        }
        // This stops move_loop once counter gets to 600
        clearInterval(move_loop);
    }
}
function moveImg() {
//This part moves all of the images 20px to the right every 10ms
    move_loop = setInterval(sliderMove, 10);
    if(img_count > 2) {
        img_count = 0;
    }
}
// This executes the moveImg function every 5 seconds
image_loop = setInterval(timer, 5000);
```

Sorry if the codes not very organized. This is the first time that I have created anything with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with that, including naming your image variables wrong.

Try this:

```
// 4 images
var image0 = new Image();
image0.src = "http://placekitten.com/200/300";
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "http://placekitten.com/205/305";
var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "http://placekitten.com/300/400";
var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "http://placekitten.com/800/600";
// array of 4 images
images = new Array(image0, image1, image2, image3);

// global counter and canvas
var counter = 0, ctx, interval;

// this is the main function
function draw(){
    myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    interval = setInterval(draw_next_image, 1000);
}

// this is the function called after each timeout to draw next image
function draw_next_image(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(images[counter], 0, 0);
    counter++;
    if (counter==images.length) {counter=0;}
}

window.onload = draw;
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/8c9MM/1/ for example. You can also pause the slideshow since we're assigning interval to the `setInterval()` function

Comment: Rob W: thanks for answering. So, you've replaced setTimeout with setInterval to create a persistent loop. But I really want to create Timeouts one at a time, not one interval for all. I can't understand, why wouldn't that work?

Comment: Ah, I think, I got it. I expected setTimeout to be synchronous, but it is asynchronous: that means, it returns instantly, when gets called and next statement is executed right away (which is clearRect). That way all the 4 iterative clearRect's run almost instantly and only then the timouts expire and my 4 `draw_next_image` functions get executed and all the 4 images are drawn on top of each other, right?

Comment: Right. If you use setTimeout, you'd need to have 4 of them... so for each iteration you had, try doing `setTimeout(function, 1000 * iteration)`. This will make them in an synchronous-like way.

Comment: Thanks! Hm, I wonder, is there no synchronous wait function in javascript at all?