# HTML5 Canvas slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a slideshow with html5 canvas and found this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931072/simplest-slideshow-in-html5-canvas-canvas-context-clearrect-not-working-with-se) which is working.

Anybody an idea how to get out of the loop?

```
  if (counter > maxNum) counter = 0;
```

Insstead of counter=0; I wanna get out of this loop, but all things I tried didn't work.
Anybody an Idea?

Comment: Which code did you use? The one of the accepted answer?

Comment: yes that's the one I used

Comment: What  hvae you tried?

Comment: I have tried break, calling a new function (not sure if this is right). But didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the draw code you have this:

```
this._draw = function() {

    //if the next image will cover the canvas
    //there is no real need to clear the canvas first.
    //I'll leave it here as you ask for this specifically
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height)
    ctx.drawImage(images[counter++], 0, 0);
    if (counter > maxNum) counter = 0;

    setTimeout(me._draw, 1000); //here we use me instead of this
}
```

the problem is that you don't have a loop there so `break` does not work.

but you can replace `if (counter > maxNum) counter = 0;` (this resets the counter)  with `if (counter > maxNum) return;` which exits the function so that `setTimeout` would not be called.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `break;`?

```
if (counter > maxNum) {
    ...
    break;
}
```

**Edit:** You might also want to try `return` ?

```
if (counter > maxNum) {
    ...
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried break but it doesn't work. If I add break I can't run the code

Comment: Break does just that, breaks out of the loop. I'm now confused as to what you're wanting.

Comment: First I wanna show 3 images with this slideshow. After the third image I wanna break out of the loop and draw a new picture on the canvas which is not part of this loop

Comment: It really depends how your code is structured. From your description the only conclusions I can draw would be `break` or `return` to achieve "... I wanna break out of the loop". Maybe post your code?